# I am getting undefined property in one place?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am new to php

I have this code

```
 $query = $request->all();
    $allParameters = $request->all();
    $keyword = 'جورج';
    $apikey = 'XXX'; 
    $googleApiUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' . $keyword . '&maxResults=' . 100 . '&key=' . $apikey;
   // dd($googleApiUrl);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $googleApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($response);
    $value = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);
    $init = new stdClass;
    $array = [];
    //dd($data->items);
     foreach($data->items as $i => $item) { 
            $i++;
            $init = new stdClass;
           //dd($item->id->videoId);
            //dd(sprintf("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s",$item->id->videoId));
            $ura = sprintf("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s",$item->id->videoId);
            $init->Nmae = $item->snippet->title;
          
          // $init->url =  sprintf("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s",$item->id->videoId);
            $init->Id = $i;
            array_push($array,$init);
            DB::table('wassoufs')->insert(
              ['Id' =>$i , 'Name' => $item->snippet->title, 'url'=>  $ura]
            );
        };
```

Undefined property: stdClass::$videoId

the `dd(sprintf("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s",$item->id->videoId));`

work fine

but when i do

```
 $ura = sprintf("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s",$item->id->videoId);
```

I get Undefined property: stdClass::$videoId

Any reason ?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening, because sometimes the videoId is empty.

[image]

You are not only getting videoIds but also channelIds.

[image]

I would do a rewrite like this if you are only interested in videoIds.

```
       $i++;
       $init = new stdClass;

       if (isset($item->id->videoId)) {

               $ura = sprintf("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s",$item->id->videoId);
               $init->Nmae = $item->snippet->title;
      
               $init->Id = $i;
               array_push($array,$init);
               DB::table('wassoufs')->insert(
                  ['Id' =>$i , 'Name' => $item->snippet->title, 'url'=>  $ura]);
          }
```

Comment: Any reason why 50 i the maxResults or youtube api not allowing more

Comment: Sure that is the maxResult per Page. Quote from the docs (Acceptable values [for maxResult] are 1 to 50) https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Comment: You need to implement a paginator -> https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination

Comment: I wanted to be lazy and get all the reusul per 1 req

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible with the YouTube API.